# How to append new data to a text file in C++ without outputting the title again?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have a problem in outputting my code to a text file. I just wanted to print a title at the beginning of a .txt file, but it happened to end up printing along with new lines of data. Basically, I am appending new data to the text file using ios::app. How can I achieve not printing my title in the text file all over again after appending other data?

[Text File Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shDnJ.png)

Here is my code btw...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void QuaranDiary();

    struct quarantine3 //structure for QuaranDiary
{
    string QuaranDiaryMonth;
    string QuaranDiaryDay;
    string QuaranDiaryYear;
    string QuaranDiaryHour;
    string QuaranDiaryMinute;
    string QuaranDiaryUpdate;
};

quarantine3 diary[500];


//QuaranDiary
void QuaranDiary()
{
    int i = 0, update = 0;
    char QuaranDiaryMore;

    do
    {
        cout << "=====================================================================================" << endl;
        cout << "                                 COVID-19 QUARANDIARY                                " << endl;
        cout << "=====================================================================================" << endl << endl;
        cout << "DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Month  : ";
        cin >> diary[i].QuaranDiaryMonth;
        cout << "Day    : ";
        cin >> diary[i].QuaranDiaryDay;
        cout << "Year   : ";
        cin >> diary[i].QuaranDiaryYear;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "[" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryMonth << "/" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryDay << "/" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryYear << "]" << endl << endl;

        cout << "TIME (23:59)"<<endl<<endl;
        cout << "Hour   : ";
        cin >> diary[i].QuaranDiaryHour;
        cout << "Minute : ";
        cin >> diary[i].QuaranDiaryMinute;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "[" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryHour << ":" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryMinute << "]" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Health Update: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, diary[i].QuaranDiaryUpdate);

        update++;

        cout << "\n\nAdd More to QuaranDiary? [Y/N]: ";
        cin >> QuaranDiaryMore;
        QuaranDiaryMore = toupper(QuaranDiaryMore);

        while (toupper(QuaranDiaryMore) != 'Y' && toupper(QuaranDiaryMore) != 'N')
        {
            cout << "\nWrong Input. Try Again!\n" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Add More to QuaranDiary? [Y/N]: ";
            cin >> QuaranDiaryMore;
        }

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        system("CLS");

        //fstream for QuaranDiary
        ofstream QuaranDiary;
        QuaranDiary.open("QuaranDiary.txt", ios::app);

        QuaranDiary << "=====================================================================================" << endl;
        QuaranDiary << "                                 COVID-19 QUARANDIARY                                " << endl;
        QuaranDiary << "=====================================================================================" << endl;;


        QuaranDiary << "\nDate: " << diary[i].QuaranDiaryMonth << "/" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryDay << "/" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryYear;
        QuaranDiary << "\tTime: " << diary[i].QuaranDiaryHour << ":" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryMinute << endl << endl;
        QuaranDiary << "[Health Update]\n\n" << diary[i].QuaranDiaryUpdate << endl;
        QuaranDiary << "=====================================================================================" << endl;

        if (QuaranDiary.is_open())
        {
            cout << "\nCheck QuaranDiary.txt for your written health updates!" << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "\n\nUnable to Open File!" << endl;
        }

        QuaranDiary.close();
    } while (toupper(QuaranDiaryMore == 'Y'));
}
```

Comment: You can just open the file forehand, read it and check whether the wanted string aka your title, is there. If it's there, skip it. If it's not, add it in the beginning

Comment: Alternatively, you could just check if it's a new file or not by testing if `QuaranDiary.tellp()` is zero after opening it.